# When your computer freezes/hangs/stalls, stays on same screen, input devices don't work - how do you say that?

Tags: translation

我的电脑。。。

冻结

失速

卡住

？

Also got - 死机了 and 当机 from another board. Any others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common one should be `死机了`, you can also say:

```
死了
不动了
没反应了
黑屏了 (got a black screen)
蓝屏了 (got a MS Windows blue error screen)
```

Answer (score 2):

Most formal/suitable sentence to be used - 当机/瘫痪。 instead of 死了，卡了，挂了,没反应

Best way to translate is

```
Chinese：我电脑当机/瘫痪了，输入设备操作不了
English：My computer crashed, input devices is not working.
```

Answer (score 1):

^_^  I think the answers you provided have been very integrated,  just mostly  we use '死机了' and '卡住了' .

Comment: Oh!  Also can say '瘫痪了' 崩溃了（breakdown)

Answer (score 0):

"當機" 的 "當" comes from its Mandarin pronunciation: dang1, which is very similar to the English pronunciation of the word "down".

It has been used since the age of punch-card computers.

Answer (score 0):

"死机了" is my best choice as it sounds native.